# How much control do I have over my information on Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

If I complete a Stack Overflow Careers CV how much is visible to other people? For example, if I filled out my work history how much of that is available to other users? Can I choose to only reveal such information to potential employers I am interested in talking to?

Comment: That's a really important question. I don't think the UI conveys the amount of public and private information in the best way possible. A good example here would be GitHub, where every page you visit has visual indicators (colors, a lock icon, a badge) that tell you immediately if a repo is private. Maybe it's just my quirk, but I like to be *absolutely* sure what I share where...

Answer (score 12):

We have a few settings that control how your CV is shown to the rest of the world. If you click the 'Settings' button in the right sidebar you'll be taken to a screen where you can control these settings:

[image: Privacy Settings]

1. 'Make Public / Private' determines whether your CV is able to be seen by other users and whether a custom URL is associated with it.
2. 'Block / Allow Search Engines' determines whether your CV can be indexed by search engines.
3. The last section controls whether your CV is visible to employers that use our [Candidate Search](http://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/careers/us/platform/candidate-search) product.

   - **Looking for a job** means that your CV will be prioritised in search results that your CV matches. Employers can send messages to you.
   - **Not looking, but open to being contacted** means that your CV will appear in search results that your CV matches. Employers can send messages to you.
   - **Block all messages and matches** means that you will **not** appear in results and cannot be messaged by employers.

It's worth noting that by default your visibility to other users is 'private' and that you must explicitly make your CV visible to the world. Visibility to employers is controlled by the value you picked when you created your CV:

[image: Create CV]

Comment: Thanks Dean! Can employers see your SO profile (and your questions/answers) or is that hidden by default? Also, what about your real name you have attached to your CV?

Comment: Also Dean .. is there a way we can see what our CV looks like to a potential employer so we can better ascertain what info they have access to?

Comment: @webworm: Just browse to your public custom cv url, incognito.

Comment: There is a button that says "Preview Public CV". That makes it sound like the information it show is public.

Comment: just to be crystal clear, if I 'set my CV to private' && it the *employer searches* is set to either 'actively look right now' *or* 'open, but not actively looking' then the employers **can** see my CV while no else can see?

Comment: just to be crystal clear, if I 'set my CV to private' && it the *employer searches* is set to either 'actively look right now' *or* 'open, but not actively looking' then the employers **can** see my CV while no else can see? @Abhitalks this is why webworm asked his question. The answer to this question is likely yes. Hopefully Dean can confirm...

Comment: Dean, can you please confirm if I've understood you correctly or not?

Comment: @Honey my answer is a little dated because we've since moved to Developer Story rather than CVs. That said, it's still the case that you can set your story to be private, but if you [search status](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) is **Actively looking** or **Open, not actively looking** then, yes, it is still visible to employers.