# How can a normal user or employer check a user's CV on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Is there any way to check a user's CV on Stack Overflow? For example, I have a CV on Stack Overflow and I can view it using this URL: `http://stackoverflow.com/cv/Here My CV or My Name`. Can I view an other user's CV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you (and anyone else, including employers) can view other user's CVs, if the user has a CV and [has set it to be public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315942/how-much-control-do-i-have-over-my-information-on-stack-overflow-careers/315943#315943).

For users which have a CV ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)), there's a big button in their profile to see it:

[image]