# What information of my profile would be revealed if I submit for a job through Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

I see job posts on Stack Overflow. The submission happens either directs you to the companies website or you can directly submit your resume through Stack Overflow ( like the image below).
[image]

If I do that submission. Other than the information that I fill on the form about. What will be revealed to person **who sees my submission**? Would they be able to see my reputation and all my stupid questions?
Also **would doing so make my resume be visible online** for future on Stack Overflow? Would other regular users be able to see more information about me?

Basically I want to know what info would be revealed afterwards?

Comment: After many posts discussing the inconsistencies in the UI of jobs I can say they still have not fixed the consistency of the button lettering and the positioning...why o why is it so difficult to change these two things?

Comment: Related questions: [Is your Stack Overflow username submitted to employers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321394/3345375) & [How much control do I have over my information on Stack Overflow Careers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315942/3345375)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you do not already have a public CV on Stack Overflow, the employer will see nothing! An employer can only see your SO account if:

1. You have a /Jobs CV.
2. You've added your SO account to it.
3. You apply using that CV.

In this case you'd just be uploading a PDF or whatnot and that's all they'd see.

We never make your CV public to the rest of our customers. Only you can do that yourself by going into the CV settings and setting yourself as a passive or active candidate.

Comment: Can you please add links for all the things you mentioned we could do? Also how can I have a jobs CV uploaded on SO, but not added to my account? If it isn't added to my account then where is it?!  Does your 2nd point mean **making it public**?

Comment: And just to be crystal clear, they would only see John Doe, johndoe@gmail.com, 888-john-doe, john doe city and JohnDoe Resume; because I uploaded my resume directly, they won't see asma22 username on SO **unless** I used my uploaded resume onto my account, correct?