# How to hide my CV profile from being indexed by Search Engines, but still can be accessed using public URL?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I don't want my CV profile on Stack Overflow Careers get indexed by search engines. But I want to be able to share it to other people via public accessible URL. Is it possible to do so?

n.b. I can't find search engine options on the right hand of Developer Story page as mentioned on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315943/1878585).

Comment: That answer you posted is old and replaced with the developer story settings found under your accounts story preferences.  If you've got it set to public it is indexed however, the setting you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have added the feature-request tag to the question. It's kinda sad to see that the Developer Story missing a feature compared to its predecessor.